# How can I deploy the Cloud setup: it always blocks at deploy saying I need a quota increase, but I already got an increase and am on a paid account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, google-cloud-billing

Cannot get the Cloud Setup deploy step to work, I always get this error:

[image: billing blocked]

I set up an organization, added a billing account. Launched the Cloud Setup checklist. All steps are done, as below:

[image: all tasks done]

but the "download or deploy" step is blocking me. I always get the message above about quotas:

- I requested and got a quota increase as suggested: no change
- I ended the free trial period and converted to a paid account, got confirmation: no change
- I requested and got a new quota increase as suggested: no change
- I reset the billing account on the project: no change
- I unlinked the project from the account, then linked it again: no change
- I created a new billing account, linked it with a card, and chose it instead of the original one: no change
- I made an advance payment to that account, and it is now credited, because a flashing message mentioned I might need to do an additional payment: no change

I have only a single project in the account, and that is the autogenerate quick setup project, so it is unlikely this is actually a quota issue. The billing account has two active credit cards enabled, so it is not a payment issue.

Whenever I revalidate the billing account, and get back to editing it, I get this quick flashing error message, which I was only able to capture using a screen capture video

[image: flashing error]

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest contacting the [Billing support team](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?visit_id=638193433865906076-32745533&rd=1) to look into your project and further investigate what might be the causing the issue.

Comment: I tried this, but their logic prevents me from contacting them because I still have free credits on my account. Catch-22.

Comment: You may feel free to contact sales at the following 1-844-613-7589 number. Please note that Sales is available Monday—Friday, 8 AM—8 PM ET. You can advise them to connect you to Billing so they can take a look at your project.